# global const variables in lua 5.4

Tags: lua, fivem

i know you're able to do constant variables in lua now with `<const>`, but they seem to only work with local variables:

`local myNumber <const> = 10 -- This works perfectly fine`

`myGlobalNumber <const> = 10 -- This causes an error`

Is it possible to have constant global variables as well?

`myGlobalNumber <const> = 10`

Comment: Constant may be only local variables.  No globals.  No table fields.  Actually, it's a quite useless Lua feature.

Comment: You can simulate const globals with _G metatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the `<const>` local variable attribute is to allow Lua to check, at "load" time (when you call `dofile` / `load` / `require` or similar), whether a local variable is not being mutated - that is, whether the only assignment is the initial one at declaration time. It is a tool to help programmers (1) express intent (2) get slightly more "load time" checking than just syntactic checks.

This works for `local` variables precisely because they are local. They are visible only within function scope. This means Lua has all the information it needs when you load a "chunk" of code (effectively a function body) to check whether it abides by the *static* (load time) rules of `<const>`.

"Globals" / "environmental variables" (as I like to call them) are effectively just syntactic sugar for accessing fields in the `_ENV` (usually `_G`) table. As such, they are much more dynamic than local variables. You could do `_G[some .. complex .. expression] = 42`, for example. With global variables, just as with any other table fields, Lua does not have all the information it needs at load time. To begin, it does not even know which fields your code will set or get. Even if it knew this, or limited itself to the `<name>` syntax, that would still be insufficient. Consider loading a file where a certain global variable that was not set yet is used (perhaps in some callback where the author knows it will be available in time). Lua can not warn about this at the time the file is loaded. (It could, at best, try to warn when the file containing the conflicting constant definitions was loaded, then warn when subsequent files are loaded.)

As ESkri has said, you can implement run-time checks to guard against accessing constant global variables via a metatable. That could look something like this:

```lua
local constants = {pi = math.pi}
setmetatable(_G, {__index = constants, __newindex = function(_, key) error("attempt to change constant global variable " .. key) end})
print(pi) -- runs fine
pi = 3 -- errors
```

However, this is probably a bad idea:

- It's likely to confuse (future) you as well as whatever static analysis tools you may choose to use. (This could be alleviated to an extent using a different implementation however.)
- It incurs a performance penalty.
- It's still only a runtime check. If you don't hit a code path in your testing, you don't get an error or warning.

Instead, I would recommend the use of *static analysis tools* such as *Luacheck*, which lets you specify [*read-only global variables* in its [configuration file](https://luacheck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html), and also supports a `new read globals` inline option to add read-only global variables, similar to a "constant" definition. Example:

```lua
-- luacheck: globals pi
pi = math.pi
-- luacheck: new read globals pi
pi = 3
```

it should be noted that while options are limited in scope to files, the `read_global` configuration field is per-"project" (folder) you're running Luacheck in. To establish `pi` as a read-only global project-wide, you could set `read_globals = {"pi"}`, then use `-- luacheck: globals pi` to make an exception where `pi` is defined (followed by `-- luacheck: new read globals pi` to revoke that exception afterwards).